# How to detect which side has been hit of a Rectangle in Java

Tags: java, java-8, collision-detection, game-physics, rectangles

I am making a game of Breakout in Java and I have come to the point where I need to be able to detect which side of the Brick has been intersected by the Ball. Currently I am using the intersects method, however this only detects intersections, not specifically which side has been hit. This is the method (I have added in some comments):

> ```
> public boolean intersects(Rectangle r) {
>     // The width of the Brick as tw
>     int tw = this.width;
>     // The height of the Brick as th
>     int th = this.height;
>     // The width of the given Rectangle as rw
>     int rw = r.width;
>     // The height of the given Rectangle as rh
>     int rh = r.height;
>     // Check if the given Rectangle or Brick does not exist
>     if (rw <= 0 || rh <= 0 || tw <= 0 || th <= 0) {
>
>         // If not, then return false because there is nothing to collide/intersect
>         return false;
>     }
>
>     // The x location of Brick as tx
>     int tx = this.brickLocation.x;
>     // The y location of Brick as ty
>     int ty = this.brickLocation.y;
>     // The x location of the given Rectangle as rx
>     int rx = r.x;
>     // The y location of the given Rectangle as ry
>     int ry = r.y;
>
>     // RW = RW + RX
>     rw += rx;
>     // RH = RH + RY
>     rh += ry;
>     // TW = TW + TX
>     tw += tx;
>     // TH = TH + TY
>     th += ty;
>
>     //      overflow || intersect
>     return ((rw < rx || rw > tx) &&
>             (rh < ry || rh > ty) &&
>             (tw < tx || tw > rx) &&
>             (th < ty || th > ry));
> }
> ```

And I have now put this method into one of my classes and I am customizing it, however I am having trouble making it so that it detects which side has been hit because the final return statement is just so interconnected, you can't just take one of those lines, because in order for it to know where that side ends it needs to know the other sides, and that's what it does here, if it has intersected all of the sides (and no limit is put on the outreach of the sides - though of course visibly they are limited) then it returns true, and if not then not and it hasn't touched the shape because otherwise it would have done.

And what I would like to be able to do is to make it so that there are if statements which decide what int is returned (I will change its return type from boolean to int), and thus which side it has hit so that it can bounce off in the appropriate fashion. But because these are so interdependent I have no idea how to separate them:

> ```
>     //      overflow || intersect
>     return ((rw < rx || rw > tx) &&
>             (rh < ry || rh > ty) &&
>             (tw < tx || tw > rx) &&
>             (th < ty || th > ry));
> ```

I have seen many similar questions here, but either they are in a different language, don't have any answers, or don't have any answers which answer the question and have been accepted. So I was wondering if anybody can suggest to me how I separate these so that it can detect which side has been hit, because I am out of ideas?
Or perhaps is there a Java method already which can do this for me and I don't have to override an already existing one? I have the latest version of the Oracle JDK 8.

Comment: I think you should draw a diagram and mark which coordinates are what; this should help you understand what that "interconnected" statement really is. Oh, and it doesn't matter in what language the other answers are written - math is always math.

Comment: If you “move” the ball by adding offsets to its coordinates, using bigger offsets for higher speed, you have to be prepared for hitting the edges without ever intersecting them in any time frame. Even worse, you could intersect the opposite edge with a very fast ball movement. Calculating edge intersections is the wrong approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do that is when moving the ball I assume you do something like this:

```
ball.x += speedX;
ball.y += speedY;
```

You can turn that to this:

```
ball.x += speedX;
if (intersects(ball, brick))
{
    //Ball touched brick on left/right side (depending if speedX is positive or negative)
}
ball.y += speedY;
if (intersects(ball, brick))
{
    //Ball touched brick on top/bottom side (depending if speedY is positive or negative)
}
```

Comment: If you go this route, you can probably have `intersects` take in another parameter indicating to check left/right or top/down. That way you don't do both checks in both sections.

Comment: @gonzo although I agree, there are ways to avoid calling `intersects()` twice, your way sounds wrong. If it only checks for left/right, in the first call, it might return true while the ball is above the brick. As long as it works, it's app to OP to to optimize it to their need.

Answer (score 0):

try to let your  intersects(Rectangle r) function return -1 in case of not hitting any sides , and 0-1-2-3 to determine the side you hit . according of what part has been incremented ..